# What to look for in a single 9v power supply for various brands of foot pedal

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I have the following foot pedals:

- [MXR Dynacomp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXR_Dyna_Comp)
- [Pro-co RAT II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_Co_RAT)
- [BOSS CE-5 (Chorus Ensemble)](http://www.bossus.com/gear/productdetails.php?ProductId=136)
- [Korg AX30G](http://www.musicgearreview.com/reviews.php?man=Korg&cat=Guitar_Effects&mod=AX30G)

... and of course would like to add more. :)

I'd like a single power supply to <strike>rule</strike> power them all (for example this [Chord 9Vdc Power Bank](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NVU9GG)).

I'm not necessarily after a recommendation per-sé, as it'll go out of date eventually. However, what should I be checking/looking for when trying to choose one of these adapters so I get one that will work without frying my gear.

I'm thinking adding up amps and checking centre-pin polarity etc, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm powering 10 pedals with a single [1spot](http://www.visualsound.net/index.php/products/pedal_power_supplies/1_spot_power_supply) power supply.
You just have to make sure that you pedal do not consume in total more that power supply output (those mA).

T-rex makes some nice power supplies.

Comment: Cool. Are the pedals all the same or do they have different brands and power requirements? Are they all centre-pin positive?

Comment: They are center pin negative and they're all different.
Korg Pitchblack, CAE MC-404, VoodooLab Microvibe, Fulltone Catalyst, Xotic AC+, Ibanez BC-9, EHX Stereo Pulsar, TC Electronic NovaRepeater.

Answer (score 2):

There are a wide range of companies that produce power supplies suitable for multiple effects. Core factors which should help your decision:

- What is the total current output? This must be higher than the total current needs of your pedals
- What is the individual current available? This must be higher than an individual pedal's needs
- Can it cope with centre positive, centre negative or odd connector types?
- How robust is it?
- How heavy is it?